# Use python variables or arrays in latex for loop

Tags: pgfplots, pythontex

**I want to access the '\j'-th element of the array in the latex for loop.**

**SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character**

```
\usepackage[top=4cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{pdfsync}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}

from numpy import *

a=7

array=[]

for i in range(0,a):
    array.append(i**2)

long=int(len(array))

\end{pycode}

\begin{center}

    \begin{pysub}
        \foreach \j in {0,...,!{long-1}}
        { 
            \( \py{array[\j]} \) \par   
        }
    \end{pysub}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**I want to access the '\j'-th element of the array in the latex for loop.**

Comment: the tag `pgfplots`? I post one answer

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is not possible, we can access with  `!{array[3]}` for example but not with `\j`.

We can prepare the loop in `python`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=4cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pythontex}
% \usepackage{pdfsync}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from numpy import *
a=7
array=[]
tab=''
for i in range(0,a):
    array.append(i**2)
#long=int(len(array))
    tab=tab+str(array[i])+r"\par"
\end{pycode}

\begin{pysub}
    !{tab}
    % !{array[0]}
    % !{array[1]}
    % !{array[2]}
    % !{array[3]}
    % !{array[4]}
    % !{array[5]}
    % !{array[6]}
\end{pysub}

% \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, the same table can be obtained by working directly in `latex`.
If you are interested, there is a tutorial here https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/ and the `interface3` documentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=4cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \llengthint %<-- your a in python

\NewDocumentCommand{\settab}{ m }%<-- to fill the table
    {
        \int_set:Nn \llengthint { #1 }%<- #1 is th paramter 
        \intarray_new:Nn \g_python_intarray { #1 }
        \int_step_inline:nn {#1}%<-- loop 
            {
                \intarray_gset:Nnn \g_python_intarray {##1} { ##1*##1 }% ##1 is the \j in a loop python
            }
    }
% \NewDocumentCommand{\looptab}{ O{1} m }
%     {
%         \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#2}
%             {
%                 \intarray_item:Nn \g_python_intarray {##1}\par
%             }
%     }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getitem}{ m }
    {
        \intarray_item:Nn \g_python_intarray {#1}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\settab{7}%<-- to fill the table 

% \looptab[4]{7}

% \looptab{5}

\foreach \j in {1,...,\llengthint}
        { 
            \( \getitem{\j} \) \par   
        }
\end{document}
```